# Why Scrapy don't return a value from function?

Tags: python, parsing, scrapy

**CODE:**

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider
from scrapy import Request


class TestSpider(CrawlSpider):
  name = "test_spyder"
  allowed_domains = ["stackoverflow.com"]
  start_urls = ['https://stackoverflow.com/tags']

  def parse(self, response):
    title_1 = response.xpath('//h1/text()').extract_first()
    next_url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/users'
    title_2 = Request(url=next_url, callback=self.parse_some)
    yield {'title_1': title_1, 'title_2': title_2}

  def parse_some(self, response):
    return response.xpath('//h1/text()').extract_first()
```

I don't understand why instead second page title (Users) i get other value (https://stackoverflow.com/users>).
Scrapy should return next values: `Tags + Users`, but returns: `Tag + <Request GET htt...` at list i think so.
Where is the error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To crawl url you need to `yield` a `Request` object. So your parse callbacks should either:

1. Yield a dictionary/`Item` - this is the end of crawl chain. The item is being generated, it is sent through pipelines and finally saved somewhere if you have that set up.
2. Yield a `Request` object - this still continues the crawl chain to another callback.

Example of this process:

1. crawl url1 (2)
2. crawl url2 (2)
3. yield item (1)

Your spider in this case should look like this:

```
def parse(self, response):
    title = response.xpath('//h1/text()').extract_first()
    yield {'title': title}

    next_url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/users'
    yield Request(url=next_url, callback=self.parse_some)
```

And your end results crawling with `scrapy crawl spider -o output.json`:

```
# output.json
[
{'title': 'title1'},
{'title': 'title2'}
]
```